# How to set the status bar to look like the system message app in iOS?

Tags: ios, toolbar, statusbar

First, look at the picture below.
[image]

The middle is the message app, the left and right are my apps.

As you can see, in the message app, the status bar and top bar are both grey.

In the left one, the top bar is not translucent. The status bar and the top bar are all white.

In the right one, the top bar is translucent, which is the default style. The top bar is grey, but the status bar is white.

My question is, how to set the status bar to grey? As I can see in the target info part, the status bar style is already 'grey style(default). But it runs in white in my iPhone 5 iOS 7.1.1.

Comment: Use UINavigationViewController

Comment: It seems there is a bug. When you first add a top bar and add two toolbar item. Everything works fine. However, when you change the item's text color, the status bar will be white and the top bar will be grey. Then you can't get things right even if you change the item text color back to default.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that @Panayot Panayotov is right. In Navigation controller, everything is fine.

I have compared the Navigation controller and Navigation bar alone. It turns out that in Navigation controller, the Navigation bar's x, y, width and height is 0, 0, 0, 0, which means it is right behind the status bar and also with a autolayout size. Since the status bar is translucent in iOS7, the color of the status bar and navigation bar are the same.

If you use Navigation bar alone, it has a fixed height 44, which can not be changed. That height can't cover the status bar and navigation bar items together. So they colors are different.

Finally the answer is to use navigation controller, not using navigation bar alone.